# Firebase package issue

Tags: firebase, flutter

> How can I solve this error when I add firebase package  flutter project to my this error message appear

```
    Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging- 
    11.1.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messagin
    g\JobIntentService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Comment: you can ignore these errors since you cannot do much about them. Your app will run without any problems.

Comment: Ok but why this error appear and how can someone solve this error ? @Ashutoshpatole

Answer (score 0):

This is not a error its a warning about your local cached flutter package file. This file you can also find if you follow the path given in the terminal or by opening directly from the IDE however its not recommended to modify those files. Commonly if such issue persists higher your `minSdkVersion` to 21 at-least because these packages require this much android sdk version and also make sure multidex is enabled and is set to true `multiDexEnabled true`